# Set label inside MATCHER rule?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

With Matcher() rules is there a way to tag/set a "label" on the token direcly in the rule f.e. :

```
[{ 'DEP' : 'ROOT', 'SET_LABEL' : 'ACTION' }],
......... many more ....
```

and then in python code :

```
if token.label == 'ACTION' : ........
```

using on_match is not useful if you have many more patterns everyone using different LABEL, because there is no feedback which MATCH occurred !?

The ideal thing will be a sort of post-spacy "parser" that act on the tagging info that spacy provide.

Answer (score 3):

You should further read the doc but basicaly you can have a file called patterns.jsonl filled with rules that look like this:

```
{"label": "LOGGIA", "pattern": [{"LOWER":"loggia"}]}
```

then you can access the labels with :

```
for ent in doc.ents :
        prediction.update({ent.label_ : ent.text})
```

You can nlp.disable_pipes('ner') if you exclusively want your labels and none other.
check this out https://course.spacy.io/ and spacy won't have secrets.
Hoping this is what you need